# How to force terminating a cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I unfortunately ran to an infinite loop of cloud function ,It's being executing since yesterday without stopping ,please don't tell me how to avoid this problem because I'm fully aware of this but I ran to this issue by mistake ,I just want to know why firebase team did not yet develop a way allowing developers to force terminating such functions.

Comment: I can't even deploy cloud functions any more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can stop a function from executing by undeploying it.  Comment it out of your index.js and run `firebase deploy` again.